# iCloud Storage Config: Photos

Tags: icloud, photos, photo-stream

I'm having trouble figuring out if my iPhone/iCloud is configured correctly? It seems odd that `Photos` is there in the `iCloud Storage` config, but then `Photo Library` is there under `Backups` config (highlighted in the green boxes)?

It seems like that should be one or the other? Am I double-storing my photos?

As a footnote, if I flip the `iCloud Photo Library` to `on` I get an error that I don't have enough space (which is what prompted the research).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not using iCloud Photo Library, iOS will treat your Camera Roll photos and any saved photos as part of the standard backup process.

You are storing all of those backed-up photos in a separate backup in your iCloud Storage (the dark blue part of your storage bar). This means that you are correct in suggesting you are "double-storing" your photos.

If you were to delete your backup from iCloud (I recommend backing up the photos on your physical device to external storage before you do this) and then turn on iCloud Photo Library, your photos would be uploaded to iCloud and then would not need to be backed up by the device.

Here is my current storage as an example:

[image: iCloud Storage showing photo size and backup size]

You can see that my photos and videos are taking the majority of my storage while my backups are only a small part.

In short: Delete your backup from iCloud (after backing up photos), turn on iCloud Photo Library, then after the photos have been uploaded, backup your device again.

Comment: cool. i'll give that a try. i still don't understand how both are in there. i mean i would have though the OS was smart enough to know the content was identical.

Comment: now i wonder if they were just "different" photos? i did what you said and deleting the backup freed up 24.5GB, but then the Photos chunk started creeping up (it's now at 30.6 GB from 25.5 GB), as well as when I click on the Photos app at the bottom it says, "4,530 Photos, 202 Videos / Uploading 4,051 Items." and when i went to turn back-ups back on it gave me a message something like, "Not enough iCloud storage." i'll let it finish what it's doing and check back in the morning. hopefully i didn't make a mess of what was already in iCloud (though your advice looks sound).

Comment: i awarded the bounty and 'correct answer' distinction given the notes and effort. in my situation i think there's something different up because when i re-enabled the backup it still looks like it's going to take up ~20 GB. which is smaller than it was, but still makes me think the back up has stuff that i'm not expecting.